# Wait for promise in a forEach loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, asynchronous, promise

I am receiving a list of books from a database as a Promise.

If the initial list of books is successfully loaded, the books are further processed by passing them to a utility function.

Inside the utility function is a forEach loop which loops over each initial book, makes an async call to get additional information, creates a new book object and adds it to an array of new books (called *updatedBooks*).

Problem: I don't know how to wait until the forEach loop is finished with every book and how to return the array of new books.

Currently, I only get one updated book instead of all

### My ultimate goal is to have the list of updated books in the *res.json()* object

**This is my current structure**

```
controller.find(req.query)
    .then(function (entities) {
        awsUtil.addInfo(entities)
            .then(function (updatedBooks) {
                res.json({
                    confirmation: "success",
                    result: updatedBooks
                })
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                res.json({
                    confirmation: "fail",
                    message: err
                })
            })
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        res.json({
            confirmation: "fail",
            message: err
        })
    })
```

**Function to get the initial books from MongoDB**

```
find: function (params) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        Book.find(params, function (err, books) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
                return
            }

            console.log("Org. Books List: ", books)
            resolve(books);
        })
    })
}
```

**Utility function to get additional information and return a new array of books**

```
addInfo: function (books) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let updatedBooks = [];

        books.forEach(function (book) {
            client.itemLookup({ //Call Amazon API to get book info
                idType: 'ISBN',
                itemId: book.isbn,
                responseGroup: 'ItemAttributes,Images'
            })
                .then(function (results) {
                    const updatedBook = {
                        // The additional info from result gets added here
                    }

                    updatedBooks.push(updatedBook);
                }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                reject(err)
            });
        })
        resolve(updatedBooks) //Return the array of new books
    })
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify the `addInfo` method so it stores the promises in an array, and return `Promise.all` instead, which will resolve when all the promises have resolved.

Assuming your methods returns a promise, and it looks like they do, something like

```
addInfo: function(books) {
  let promises = books.map(function(book) {
    return client.itemLookup({
      idType        : 'ISBN',
      itemId        : book.isbn,
      responseGroup : 'ItemAttributes,Images'
    }).then(function(results) {
      return {
        // The additional info from result gets added here
      }
    });
  })
  return Promise.all(promises); // catch errors where you call "addInfo"
}
```

Comment: can you help me in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48683679/how-to-handle-database-asynchronous-operation-in-ionic-2-3/48686457#48686457